# Unable to install "'en_core_web_sm'"

Tags: jupyter-notebook, spacy, jupyter-lab, spacy-3

I have installed the spacy 3.1.2 and trying to install en_core_web_sm on jupyter notebook in Jupyterlab by using

```
!python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

but it is showing the following error

```
2021-09-01 07:00:12.028366: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-09-01 07:00:12.028469: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-09-01 07:00:12.028486: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 488, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1934, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1671, in _raise_ssl_error
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 932, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 371, in connect
    ssl_context=context,
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 384, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 494, in wrap_socket
    raise ssl.SSLError("bad handshake: %r" % e)
ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spacy-models/master/compatibility.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup_cli()
  File "/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/cli/_util.py", line 69, in setup_cli
    command(prog_name=COMMAND)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/typer/main.py", line 497, in wrapper
    return callback(**use_params)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 35, in download_cli
    download(model, direct, sdist, *ctx.args)
  File "/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 67, in download
    compatibility = get_compatibility()
  File "/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 78, in get_compatibility
    r = requests.get(about.__compatibility__)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spacy-models/master/compatibility.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

Due to this, I can't use

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

Because it is showing error as:

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

I have searched various post and articles related to it but nothing is working for me.
Can anyone tell me how to resolve this error ? It would be very helpful for me.

Comment: It looks like you are having SSL issues, are you on a corporate network or something? See the requests docs. https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

Comment: Yes polm23, I am on corporate network. I will go through the link. Thank you.