# Installing en_core_web_sm package for spaCy library in Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: python-3.x, installation, spacy

I'm trying to install the en_core_web_sm package from the spaCy library in python.

I ran the commands listed on [spaCy's website](https://spacy.io/usage) in my Ubuntu terminal:

```
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

The installation seems to have completed successfully:

```
Collecting en-core-web-sm==3.7.0
  Downloading https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.7.0/en_core_web_sm-3.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (12.8 MB)
...
✔ Download and installation successful
You can now load the package via spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

However, when I run

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

in a Jupyter notebook, I keep getting the error

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

even when I refresh everything.
What could've gone wrong?
I've looked through many related stack overflow posts such as ["spacy can't find model en-core-web-sm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334304/spacy-cant-find-model-en-core-web-sm-on-windows-10-and-python-3-5-3-anacon) and ["unable to install en-core-web-sm"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69009268/unable-to-install-en-core-web-sm); none of them helped with my issue. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by simply typing the same commands directly in Jupyter notebook (rather than in the Terminal):

```
!pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
!pip install -U spacy
!python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Now

```
spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

no longer throws any errors!

(I can't believe I didn't think of this earlier; hopefully this helps others who have encountered the same issue.)